# MATLAB code not running after displaying plot

Tags: matlab, plot

Hi I have the following MATLAB code:

```
clear all; close all; clc;
Data = xlsread('Bulk Metallic Glasses Master.xlsx','D2:AK180');
k = find(isnan(Data));
Data(k) = 0;
[~,E1,~] = xlsread('Bulk Metallic Glasses Master.xlsx','A2:A180');
[~,E2,~] = xlsread('Bulk Metallic Glasses Master.xlsx','B2:B180');
[~,S,~] = xlsread('Bulk Metallic Glasses Master.xlsx','C2:C180');
DPts = Data(:,[17,18,21,22,25,26,29,30,33,34]);
m = 0;
n = 0;

figure
hold on
for i=1:length(Data)
if Data(i,11)==1
    for j=1:2:10
        if (DPts(i,j+1) && DPts (i,j) == 0)
            return
        else
        plot(DPts(i,j+1),DPts(i,j),'r*')
        m = m+1;
        end
    end
elseif Data(i,11) == 0
    for u=1:2:10
        if (DPts(i,u+1) && DPts (i,u) == 0)
            return
        else
        plot(DPts(i,u+1),DPts(i,u),'b*')
        n = n+1;
        end
    end
end
end
hold off

g = 1;
for l=1:2:10
    x{g} = reshape(DPts(:,l:l+1),[],2);
    g=g+1;
end
```

This code is supposed to plot a graph and then reshape the source matrix and store it in a cell array.

The code runs till the plot and displays the plot but after that it doesn't run. neither does it show any error messsage. I tried running them separately and they work fine but they won't run together. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Edit: I realized it was a problem I was facing because of the return function.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't run"?

Comment: It doesn't display the output for the last part of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your program is freezing at this last step, try preallocating your cell array `x` before filling it up in your for loop.

Here's one way you could rewrite the last part with preallocating your cell araay

```
x = cell(4,1);
for k=1:2:9
    x{(k+1)/2} = reshape(DPts(:,k:k+1),[],2);
end
```